# How do I put an API request into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying convert an open source API pull from the NHTSA to ultimately go into a dataframe and onto a csv.  I'm getting the error `TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator.`

Here is the code...no password necessary.

```
import requests, json;
import pandas as pd;
import io;

url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/';
post_fields = {'format': 'csv', 'data':'1HD1JBB433Y031504;1HD1FB4138Y670512;JH2RC44553M701813;JYAVN01EX9A001399'};
r = requests.get(url, data=post_fields);
df = pd.DataFrame(io.StringIO(r.text))
```

Thank you for anyone who can help.

Comment: Try `df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(r.text))` if the API returns json. Also, do a `if r.status_code == 200` check to check if the API has returned something valid.

Comment: I checked your example, the API returns a status_code 405, so your API request is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original question:

For csv it works this way

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io
url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/'
post_fields = {'format': 'csv', 'data':'1HD1JBB433Y031504;1HD1FB4138Y670512;JH2RC44553M701813;JYAVN01EX9A001399'}
r = requests.post(url, data=post_fields)

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text), sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out!  Thank you @576i.

```
import requests, json;
import pandas as pd;
import io;

url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/';
post_fields = {'format': 'json', 'data':'1HD1JBB433Y031504;1HD1FB4138Y670512;JH2RC44553M701813;JYAVN01EX9A001399'};
r = requests.post(url, data=post_fields);
x = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(x['Results'])
```